# Stop Margin From Extending Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent and child div, and when I add margin to the child div, it expands the parent div. How can I stop this from happening. You can see it happen here because the scroll bars appear.

I had a look at this similar question but I it doesn't seem like that answer does anything.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I would like this to be the final output. With the Orange div being 100% height

Comment: Lemme know if my solution works for you... `:)`

Comment: Dude, check out my answer. It's the same like what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

When you want the margins to collapse on the child `div`, give `overflow: hidden` to the parent `div`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now there's no scrollbars. I have used `padding` on the parent instead of `margin`. Please **don't** use `calc()` - not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry man, check my edit. I would like the green div to have a padding around it. But DON'T just add padding to the parent. I need the margin to do this (in my program this would make sense)

Comment: @Frank You have conflicting heights! You might need to redo it. I'll write a different one... Give me a few moments.

Comment: @Frank `height:calc(100% - 20px)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, that's a worst idea... `:(`

Comment: @Frank Check my answer now... `:D`

Comment: he said : **don't add padding**

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you very much my man! :)

Comment: @Frank You are welcome! `:D`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Grrr. yeah.

Comment: Ah wait man, I said you should please not add padding to the parent. Check my comment up here

Comment: and am sure he's thanking you for the calc ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your answer is actually perfect haha. Sorry for ignoring you man! Add it as an official answer then I can mark it as the answer....thanks XD

Comment: @Frank `calc` can be okay, but might not work in some cases. So use with caution... `:)`